# ChoiceType with ValueObject from API

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, php-7.4

I have a form type

```
$subscriptions = []//array of Subscription

$builder
    ->add('subscription', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $subscriptions,
        'choice_label' => 'code'
    ])
;
```

I have the error:

> Cannot read index "subscription" from object of type "App\ValueObject\Company" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess.

Company is a value object that contain a `$subscription` property (`Subscription`)

```
class Company
{
    private Subscription $subscription;

    // ......
}
```

Do you know why I have the error? I want to let the user choose between some subscriptions that are VO from another API

Comment: seems like Symfony is trying to use your Company Subscription as the choices, can you share the whole code of your form ?